# How to humanize duration in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs, ngtable

I am using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) to show duration in `Y M D HH:mm:ss` format depending on duration if it includes year, month, day, hour, minutes & seconds, with ngTable sorting and filter on this field.

Code

```
  $scope.getTableDataDuration = function(item) {
      if (angular.isDefined(item) && item != null) {
          var tmp = "";
          if (item > 31536000) { //year
              tmp = moment.duration(item, "year").format("Y M D h:mm:s");
              return tmp;
          } else if (item > 2628000) { //month
              tmp = moment.duration(item, "month").format("M D h:mm:s");
              return tmp;
          } else if (item >= 86400) { //day
              tmp = moment.duration(item, "days").format("D h:mm:s");
              return tmp;
          } else if (item < 60) {
              return item;
          } else if (item < 3600) { //minute
              tmp = moment.duration(item, "minutes").format("h:mm:s");
              return tmp;
          }
      }
      return;
  }
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UcGkijvhYvRrGyAHSSzr?p=preview)

**Update**

So for example:

```
duration in seconds 331 should show 05:51
duration in seconds 7245 should show 02:01:25 
similarly till years
```

Given a duration, I need to humanize it similar to above example

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @DavidVotrubec: Need to humanize duration which is in seconds

Comment: Well, I still don't understand, what actually does not work. If duration is less then 60 seconds, then it simply outputs the number of seconds. Is that not correct?

Comment: @DavidVotrubec: Yes that is correct but for higher duration it is not giving correct humanized value. In plunker example given in question for `99544` duration it translates to `99544 0:00:0` instead it should show `1 15:21:29`

Comment: I've posted answer. I guess that all your calls to `moment.duration(item, "XXXX")` should actually be `moment.duration(item, "seconds")` because the value provided is number of seconds (not years, days etc). Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you misunderstood the documentation. I did not use `moment-duration` personally, but from the documentation on GitHub it seems that what you want to use is this

```
  moment.duration(99544, "seconds").format("D h:mm:s");
```

It informs the Duration plugin, that the input number is in seconds, which it is. And then you format it via the provided format string.

See this example https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#weeks

Here he uses `moment.duration(123, "days").format("w W", 2);` which basically says "I have 123 days and I want to convert it to number of weeks"